# Centos 5.6 switching/migration from apache to lighttpd

Tags: migration, lighttpd, php5, centos5, apache-2.2

I'm currently running Apache 2 with PHP 5.1.6 running as mod_php on a Centos 5.6 box.

I use .htaccess for mostly redirection.
I already have latest APC running `apc.so`.
I also have MySQL, etc.

Until recently I've been reading things like;

- Running php as fastcgi benefits on high traffic sites.
- Using squid as a proxy for static content.

All this time my confusion is increasing, until I finally landed on lighttpd which seems to encompass all those optimizations.

Problem is, there is no up to date article covering the complete migration from Apache to lighttpd.

Secondly, I've read a little on lighttpd being used as a proxy for Apache serving static content.

Which is better? Complete migration or start from scratch using lighttpd or simply setting httpd as a proxy.

Comment: What problem are you trying to fix? Low memory? High CPU? Complex config you want simplified?  Or just a general interest in moving from Apache to lighttpd?  Why you want to migrate makes a difference, also it depends how many sites you've got, etc.

Comment: Subjective opinion: NGINX is better than lighttpd. Also you should probably provide more details, are you using any kind of config/management tool (CPanel, Webmin etc.). Are you running custom applications or standard FOSS software (Wordpress, Joomla PHPBB etc.).

Comment: ok sorry, low memory was a big factor. anyway. ive installed nginx as a front end for apache serving static content. it was very easi and straight forward http://jamescacchione.net/featured-articles/experiments-with-varnish-nginx-apache-on-centos

Answer (score 1):

There's no up-to-date article on switching from apache to lighttpd because, for all practical purposes, lighttpd has been replaced by nginx.  Lighttpd was great for it's day, but I'm afraid it hasn't got anything going for it now.

I'd make a complete migration to nginx; I've not had a need for an Apache-specific feature in years.